# bundle exec rake secret cannot load such file -- phusion_passenger/rack_handler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, rake

When I run this command to generate secret on production server. I followed the installation documentation from the official website of Passenger, since I'm using Passenger with NGINX.
The URL to the documentation can be found here: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/aws/nginx/oss/rubygems_rvm/deploy_app.html:

**bundle exec rake secret**

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-20-167 feutradmin]$ bundle exec rake secret
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- phusion_passenger/rack_handler
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
/var/www/html/feutradmin/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/html/feutradmin/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/var/www/html/feutradmin/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:24:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:304:in `exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/exe/bundle:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/exe/bundle:19:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
gem "passenger", ">=5.0.25", require: "phusion_passenger/rack_handler"
```

followed by **bundle install** to get rid of the error.